# Twitter webscraping empty list Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, twitter

I am trying to scrape Twitter for some results and it's throwing me below error

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = u'https://twitter.com/search?q='
query = u'q=cruise&src=typed_query'

r = requests.get(url+query)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

tweets = []

for item in soup.findAll('span',attrs={"class":"css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0"}):
    result = [item.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
    tweets.append(result.text.encode("utf-8"))

f = open('search.csv', 'w')
f.write(r.text)
```

when I try to print (tweets) it gives, me an empty list, and for f.write(r.text) it gives me the below error

```
'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f602' in position 17391: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: you have the most common problem with modern pages: `twitter` uses `JavaScript` to add elements to `HTML` but `request` / `beautifulsoup` can't run JavaScript. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript`. OR you should use `Twitter API` to get data without scraping.

Comment: check `print('\U0001f602')`  - it gives me emoji  . You may have to set encoding when you write it - `open(..., encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: eventually you should get `r.content` (bytes before decoding) instead of `r.text` (string after decoding) and save it in `bytes` mode - `open(..., 'wb')`

Comment: Thank you.I tried it with Selenium and it worked